# Setting CNAMEs to CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, domain-name, aws-certificate-manager

I'm trying to set my domain name to my website.

I went to set CNAMEs to my domain name `example.com` at AWS CloudFront, when I try to save the edit I'm given the following error by AWS.

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidViewerCertificateException: To add an alternate domain name (CNAME) to a CloudFront distribution, you must attach a trusted certificate that validates your authorization to use the domain name. For more details, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-requirements (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate; Request ID: e30a1b51-b467-4128-a88c-e758bb99f0dc)
```

Yes, I'm aware of [Amazon CloudFront enhances the security](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-cloudfront-enhances-the-security-for-adding-alternate-domain-names-to-a-distribution/). Which is why I have created Certificate Manager @ **N.Virgina** for the domains I wanted (it's currently in **Issued status**)

However both the RadioButton and TextField are always in disabled mode, I never get to choose my Certificate. If I tap into Request or Import a certificate with ACM, it always bring me back to the [same webpage](https://console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home?region=us-east-1#/wizard/) for Request a certificate

What's my mistake here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unbelievable solution. I basically just need to re-login my AWS, both the option (RadioButton and TextField) is actually enabled.

Comment: this is consistency issue in large system like AWS. In same case, you need to wait some amount of time